# What is OpenGL as a computer file

Tags: opengl

Ok, I know that online there are millions of answers to what OpenGL is, but I'm trying to figure out what it is in terms of a file on my computer. I've researched and found that OpenGL acts as a multi-platform translator for different computer graphics cards. So, then, is it a dll?
I was wondering, if it's a dll, then couldn't I download any version of the dll (preferably the latest), and then use it, knowing what it has?

EDIT: Ok, so if it's a windows dll, and I make an OpenGL game that uses a late version, what if it's not supported on someone else's computer with an earlier version? Am I allowed to carry the dll with my game so that it's supported on other windows computers? Or is the dll set up to communicate with the graphics card strictly on specific computers?

OpenGL is constantly being updated (whatever it is). How can this be done if all it's doing is communicating with a graphics card on a bunch of different computers that have graphics cards that are never going to be updated since they're built in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two "parts" to OpenGL - the specification that's updated by the Khronos Group once every few months, and the driver that's written by your graphics card manufacturer specifically for your graphics card model.

The OpenGL specification essentially details how everything about the OpenGL API should work - what the expected behavior should be, when something is considered unexpected behavior, when to throw which errors, etc. The specification lets the driver writers know exactly what they need to do and lets application writers know what to expect from a driver. This is what OpenGL really "is" - the glue that holds applications and drivers together. [You can read all the specifications for each version here.](http://www.opengl.org/registry/)

Then there's drivers that implement the OpenGL API and are considered compliant to the specification. The driver does exactly what you'd expect it to do - copy data to and from the graphics card's memory, write data to graphics card registers, keep track of state, process vertices, compile shaders, instruct hundreds of stream processors to simultaneously transform vertices and fill pixels, etc. Without OpenGL, each graphics card model would have a separate, slightly faster API that would only work for that one graphics card because of the way it was structured. With OpenGL, the drivers are all written against the same API and an application's code will run on all graphics cards.

Compliance to the OpenGL specification doesn't change with driver updates. Most driver updates will either fix minor bugs or do some internal optimizing.

I know at one point there was a small bug with ATI driver where you had to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` before you could generate mipmaps the OpenGL 3 way (`glGenerateMipMaps()`) despite `GL_TEXTURE_2D` being deprecated as a possible value for `glEnable()`. I'm not sure if it's fixed now, but it's certainly the type of edge case that can easily be overlooked by driver writers.

As for optimizations, there's a lot to optimize. Maybe there's another way to optimize shaders when they're being compiled, maybe there's a more efficient way to distribute work between the stream processors, I don't know.

Comment: Be careful how you use the word "driver". In terms of the operating system, you're actually talking about libraries. Drivers are a completely different beast.

Comment: OpenGL's current version is now 4.2. Now, as far as I know, you can't expect version 2.1 or 3.0 code to compile with version 4.2, because 4.2 has a pretty different set of functions (right?). So, basically, these functions are added and changed to operate more efficiently than the earlier versions?

Comment: @AUTO You *can* expect 2.1 or 3.0 code to compile with version 4.2, because the specification was built to be forward-compatible from the ground up.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) is a cross-platform [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for graphics programming. In terms of compiled code, it will be available as an OS-specific library - e.g. a DLL (opengl32.dll) in Windows, or an SO in Linux.

You can get the SDK and binary redistributables from [OpenGL.org](http://www.opengl.org/)

Depending on which language you're using, there may be OpenGL wrappers available. These are classes or API libraries designed to specifically work with your language. For example, there are .NET OpenGL wrappers available for C# / VB.NET developers. A quick Google search on the subject should give you some results.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL API occasionally has new versions released, but these updates are backwards-compatible in nature. Moreover, new features are generally added as extensions, and it's possible to detect which extensions are present and only use those which are locally available and supported... so you can build your software to take advantage of new features when they're available but still be able to run when they aren't.

The API has nothing to do with individual drivers -- drivers can be updated without changing the API, and so the fact that drivers are constantly updated does not matter for purposes of compatibility with your software. On that account, you can choose an API version to develop against, and as long as your target operating systems ships with a version of the OpenGL library compatible with that API, you don't need to worry about driver updates breaking your software's ability to be dynamically linked against the locally available libraries.

Comment: So, the portion of OpenGL that keeps changing is the 'driver' portion? and the API part is constant? What, then, does this 'driver' part do?

Comment: There's no driver portion of OpenGL - he's talking about your graphics card drivers, which the OpenGL library talks to. All graphics card drivers implement a particular standard, so different graphics APIs (e.g. DirectX, OpenGL) can talk to them, and the OS knows how to talk to them too.